# How can I include php file in Laravel-6?

Tags: php, laravel, include

**views/spa.blade.php**

```
<?php
@include('shared.sloi'); 
?>
```

**views/shared/sloi.blade.php**

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

how to display 'hello world' in spa.blade ?

Comment: Why are you using `<?php` in blade files ? The aim of blade templating system is to override this

Comment: `@php
echo "Hello World";
@endphp  @include('shared.sloi') `  don't use php tag <?php ?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Try like below code : (without PHP code)

```
<div class="main_container">
    @include('shared.sloi')
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but here's how you would:

#### views/shared/sloi.blade.php

```php
@php
echo "gopher";
@endphp
```

#### views/spa.blade.php

```php
@include('shared.sloi')
```

Don't use `<?php?>` in blade; if you need to include php elements, use `@php (php code here) @endphp`. For other blade directives like `@include` or `@foreach`, you don't need to surround it with anything, since Laravel does all the processing for you.

On a seperate note, if you need to use `echo`, use Laravel's brackets instead:

```php
{{"gopher"}}
```

would be identical to

```php
@php
echo "gopher";
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

Check laravel documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "php" tag. laravel provide a blade template engine. just use

```
@include('shared.sloi')
```

Or

```
@include('shared/sloi')
```